# How Do I Start Editing The Chromium Source Code And Where Do I Get It?

Tags: git, chromium

Well, I know that the code for Chromium is [here.](https://chromium.org) But, how do I import the code and edit it? And in what editor? They said to do

```
git clone https://chromium.googleource.com/chromium/src
```

but I am just using zsh on a mac. So, how do I do the `git` command on there?

Comment: Do you have git installed?

Comment: What happens when you run `git --version` from zsh?

Comment: `brew install git-core` (or how is it nowadays to get the latest Git on Mac?) Possible XCode installation has it.

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/developers